# Should i store data that need to be cast into variable first? or call Dictionary indexer more than once?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, memory-management, collections

**I don't really know how to phrase this well but I confused about performance**

I have variables that read from the dictionary. but sometimes it can contain null.

For example, I have the following:

```
Dictionary<string,object> DataRow = new Dictionary<string,object>();
```

The previous line is reading Row from database Table and fetch it into Dictionary.

Now we can say we have columns: **"StudentID : `int` ", "StudentName : `varchar`", "IsPaid : `bit`"**

Sometimes Columns can be null. and I don't want to use nullable:

**Now I try to do the following:** *First Approach*

```
var StudentIDObject = DataRow["StudentID"];
var StudentID = StudentIDObject is null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(StudentIDObject);

var IsPaidObject = DataRow["IsPaid"];
var IsPaid = IsPaidObject is null ? true : Convert.ToBoolean(IsPaidObject); // note that sometimes null well be true depending on option behaviour.
```

I fell the previous code is ok and performance well be good. but it's not readability. depending I have more than 25 variables. I just give a simple example.

**Why just don't use the following ?** *Second Approach*

```
var StudentID = DataRow["StudentID"] is null ? 1 : Covnert.ToBoolean(DataRow["StudentID"]);
```

**Note** that the previous line will call the dictionary indexer two times. which I think searches in the dictionary again. is this leaks performance?

Should I use the first approach or second approach? and why?

Note that I have more than 25 variables. so that I try to figure out which is good performance while reading ? does it matter? ...

See Reference .NET source. [Dictionary](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) always doing loop when indexer called.

```
  public TValue this[TKey key] {
            get {
                int i = FindEntry(key);
                if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
                ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
                return default(TValue);
            }
            set {
                Insert(key, value, false);
            }
        }

private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
        if( key == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        }

        if (buckets != null) {
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
            for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: 3rd approach use some of the lightweight ORM

Comment: "*I try to figure out which is good performance while reading ? does it matter?*" only you (or your users) can answer that.

Comment: hmmm you have something like `SELECT StudentID, StudentName , IsPaid FROM Table` you store it in the `DataTable`(prolly in `DataSet`) ... so in fact you may also have `IEnumerable<YourDataRow>` where `class YourDataRow { public int StudentID  {get;set;} public bool? IsPaid {get;set;} public string StudentName {...} }`... with some lightweigth ORM you can can obtain it like `connection.Query<YourDataRow>(sql)` or `connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<..>(sql)` if you need only one

Comment: ok ... set default value on writting to dictionary not on reading ... or better - use custom data class which has all needed properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion on the performance is, it doesn't matter.  How fast C#, as compared to accessing a database, is basically irrelevant.

My opinion on the readability is this:

You should have a function that reads each type of value from a DataRow and converts it into the correct type:

```
var StudioId = ReadAsInt(DataRow["StudentId"]);
var IsPaid = ReadAsBoolean(DataRow["IsPaid"]);
```

Is much easier to read than your version.  You will require those functions, of course, so something like:

```
int ReadAsInt(object value)
{
    return value is null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
int ReadAsBool(object value)
{
    return value is null ? true : Convert.ToBoolean(value);
}
```

**Or use Generic-Version**

```
 public static class Conversion
    {
        public static T Read<T>(object Value, T DefaultValue = default(T))
        {
            if (Value is null || Value is DBNull)
                return DefaultValue;

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Value, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, till me should use ReadAsInt() use the Generic-version instead or it deosn't matter ?

Comment: Generic is better, mainly because it's easier to maintain one function to do everything than one per type.